# Event click on youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, jquery, preventdefault

I'm working with Youtube API and Jquery. With a certain script I can get Youtube Feeds as an image, take a look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfysr/1/)

I'm trying to do a Jquery click event which will have to invoke another script called 'embedly' like this:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).embedly({
    chars: 220,
    nostyle: true,
    key:':41f042ec20b04dda84448dc4a46d357d'
}); 
});
```

It doesn't seem to work. When I do this from my desktop the click does not invoke the embedly part and also goes to the url regardless of the prevent default.

Comment: Are all anchors already loaded when this part of the script runs?

Comment: @Asad I think so yes, the click event is at the very bottom

Comment: No, I just set a breakpoint in a debugger, and the anchor is not loaded when you attach the event.

Comment: @Asad I solved the problem with 'on window load' but I rather not do it this way...What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation to ensure the handler will be triggered regardless of when the anchor comes into the DOM:

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).embedly({
        chars: 220,
        nostyle: true,
        key:':41f042ec20b04dda84448dc4a46d357d'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfysr/3/

Comment: Haha Im familiar with this but I alway's forget about it:) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Youss That video is hilarious!